# ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "User.institucion" must be a "Institucion" instance

Tags: python, django

Recibo el siguiente error cuando intento crear un superususario en Django.

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "User.institucion" must be a "Institucion" instance.
```

Estoy intentado crear un superusuario para ingresar al administrador de Django.
Este es un fragmento del archivo models.py

```
class Institucion(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre
    
class Meta:
    ordering = ['nombre']
    
class User(AbstractUser):
choicenotificacion =  [
    ('1', 'Activo'),
    ('0', 'Inactivo')
   ] 
notificacion = models.CharField(max_length=1,default=1,choices=choicenotificacion)
email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
celular = models.CharField('Celular',max_length=30,unique=True)    
institucion = models.ForeignKey(Institucion,related_name='Institucion' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','celular','institucion']
def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

este es un fragmento del archivo Views.py

def login(request):

```
autenticacion = Authform()
#autenticacion = AuthenticationForm()

if(len(request.POST)>0 ):
    if request.method == "POST":       
        loginform = Authform(data=request.POST)
        #loginform = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        
        if loginform.is_valid():
            loginform.save()
            username = loginform.cleaned_data['username']
            password = loginform.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                do_login(request,user)
                token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                print(token[0])
                #request.POST = request.POST.copy()
                #request.POST['Token'] = token
               
                servicios = Servicio.objects.filter(institucion=request.user.institucion.id)
                return render(request,'servicios.html',{'contexto':'Panel de control','Servicios':servicios,'Token':token[0]})     
                
        else:                
            
            #return render(request,'login.html',{'auth':autenticacion,'message':{'value':"alert alert-danger",'message':'Error, datos incorrectos.'} })
            return render(request,'login.html',{'auth':autenticacion,'message':{'value':"alert alert-danger",'message': str(loginform.errors)} })
            #redirect login
else:

    return render(request,'login.html',{'auth':autenticacion})
```

Como puedo corregir ese error, no se que es lo que tengo mal, Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema tal y como dice el error es que institucion ha de ser instancia de tu modelo Institucion. Prueba esto:

```
institucion_instancia = Institucion.objects.filter(id=request.user.institucion.id)
servicios = Servicio.objects.filter(institucion=institucion_instancia)
```

Esto debería devolverte el objeto Instutición con el identificador que has pasado desde el request, y al ser clave foranea hacer la referencia de ese objeto a tu modelo Servicios.

Espero te sirva

Comment: No me sirvió amigo, me sigue generando el mismo error :(

Comment: "request.user.institucion.id" es parte de la lista que llega en request?? o quizas hayas mezclado sin querer?. Es decir, tienes una variable user por ahi y demás, no se si la referencia es correcta a la hora de buscar en el modelo Institucion.